# select multiple array elements at once

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

a very basic `Array` question but I don't know how to do this in the best possible way.

I have an array

```
var pathArr = [element1, element2, element3, element4, element5, element6]
```

what can I do if I want to select multiple elements of this path at once.

Lets say:

```
pathArr[0-2].dofunction()
```

in this example I'm doing the function on the first three elements.

or

```
pathArr[1,6].dofunction()
```

in this example only on element1 and element6

Is there something I can do with an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Iterate through your array and apply your method to each appropriate item.

You could use `slice` to return a range of items in an array, which might make it easier for you, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Should note that `slice` is only helpful for the first example, since the elements are a contiguous subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can solve this easily with the following one liners:

```
pathArr.slice(0,2).forEach(x=>dofunction(x))
```

To select multiple elements from the array you can use a map function, like so:

```
[1,6].map(x=>pathArr[x]).forEach(x=>dofunction(x))
```